# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: *[id="xxx"]

Tags: node.js, webstorm, cucumberjs

I am using `cucumber js` which is integrated with `node js` and I am successful in login screen. The only problem is: what is the syntax and methodology to wait for execution of next command, or wait for the element?

Please help me with the support code.
I got below error:

`(node:17660)
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)`

Comment: Hello, please give a minimal example of your code so that users can understand what you did. You will find tips here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am using Given, when and Then . so while code write in when then it throws you can wait maximum 5 second

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `await` by the looks of it.

Take a look at how async / await works https://javascript.info/async-await

so for example

```
await element.click();
```